# TypeError: must be real number, not MonthEnd

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 attributes:

- a = 2018-10 (type = )
- b = 2018-03 (type = )
- c = 2 (type = int)

I want to calculate an answer below (I expect the answer to be an integer):

```
answer = math.floor((a - b) / c)
```

Then I get the error message TypeError: must be real number, not MonthEnd. I want the answer to be an integer so I have unsuccesfully tried:

```
answer = math.floor(int(a - b) / c)
```

Comment: Try `(a-b).n//c`

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang, this is working perfectly and can hence be considered the answer. Could you elaborate on why this works and not my previous code?

Comment: In your code, a and b are MonthEnd periods, so is (a-b). And pandas provides a property `n` to access the number of months.